# OpenSSL: FATAL - OPENSSL_Uplink(5C149000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink in C# wrapper for C++ DLL

Tags: c#, c++, openssl

```
---------------------------
OpenSSL: FATAL
---------------------------
OPENSSL_Uplink(5C149000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink
```

I have a C++ dll, and it is using the openssl libraries (ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll) to install certificates on the machine. Our application is developed in WPF and C# with the Microsoft.Net Framework v4.8 and VS 2019. So we have to call C++ functions and pass the physical path of the certificates (.P12) to the functions. We have created C++ and C# wrappers using p/invoke. I am getting OPENSSL_Uplink(5C149000,08): no OPENSSL_Applink" and the application is crashing.

I have traced the crash to exactly where it is happening while calling the function "PKCS12* p12 = d2i_PKCS12_fp(fileDesc, NULL);."

I have tried to fix the issue by including #include <openssl/applink.c> and calling the function OPENSSL_Applink(); but it did not resolve the issue. When I include applink.c in the C++ wrapper, resharper gives me a warning: "Suspicious #include of file with '.c' extension [bugprone-suspicious-include]"

I got the below information online.

> "It raises error 'no OPENSSL_Applink()' on Windows if the application
> executable using the library does not use `#include <openssl/applink.c>` which is not always possible, i.e. for DLLs or if the calling executable is not written in C/C++.
>
> The applink.c to the DLL project didn't get rid of the error like I
> hoped it  would, and after analyzing the OpenSSL code I discovered to
> my dismay  that it always looks in the EXE for the OPENSSL_Applink
> function.  Since  this app is a C# project, adding applink.c to it is
> pretty much impossible."

So I have written a C++ console test application and it's working fine. The issue is only with the .Net environment. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem occurs when passing "FILE *" pointers between the application and OpenSSL. You are supposed to compile and link the applink.c file into your application to work around this problem. You do not need to call the "OPENSSL_Applink" function yourself (its essentially a callback that OpenSSL itself calls). Documentation for it is here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/OPENSSL_Applink.html

If for some reason you are unable to compile and link applink.c into your application then there is a possible work around, i.e. simply do not pass "FILE *" around and instead use BIOs. So, in your case, instead of calling `d2i_PKCS12_fp` you can instead call `d2i_PKCS12_bio`. You can open a new file for reading via a BIO using `BIO_new_file`:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/BIO_new_file.html

Comment: Matt Caswell, thanks for the answer. I have used BIO_new_file and d2i_PKCS12_bio and it is working fine. But now I am getting no openssl issue at the below line

"m_publicCert.avail = (1 == PEM_write_X509(fileDesc, cert))".

I have updated the latest code in the question.

Comment: I don't have experience on openssl and C++.  I just wrote a C# wrapper for the C++ DLL. So don't know what methods to call to aviod FILE* of the below lines.
FILE* fileDesc = m_publicCert.writer.Initialize();
m_publicCert.avail = (1 == PEM_write_X509(fileDesc, cert));
fileDesc = caCert->writer.Initialize();
caCert->avail = (1 == PEM_write_X509(fileDesc, cert));
fileDesc = m_privateKey.writer.Initialize();
m_privateKey.avail = (1 == PEM_write_PrivateKey(fileDesc, pkey, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL));

Comment: PEM_write_X509 can be replaced with PEM_write_bio_X509. PEM_write_PrivateKey can be replaced with PEM_write_bio_PrivateKey.

Comment: Thanks @Matt Casweel, I have removed all file handler calls and replaced with BIO calls, It worked for me.